# How to type some special mathematical expressions or symbols

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, tikz-cd, mathtools

I have a problem with typing some special mathematical expressions or symbols. They are

## 1:

[image]

## 2:

[image]

## 3:

[image]

and I need a refined form of
[image]
in which the `\right>` is typed better than it is.

Comment: Each of them is straightforward to obtain with simple arrays or `tikz-cd` or other tools. However, I fear that if you expect somebody to convert all of these screen shots to LaTeX code, you may be waiting a long time.

Comment: Dear @Schrödinger's cat, what is the `tikz-cd `? I have never heard of it.

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-cd to get an idea.

Comment: The angle brackets are not generally available in sizes larger than you get in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={dash},column sep=0.2ex]
 & & \mathfrak{u}(6)\arrow[lld]\arrow[rrd]\arrow[d] & & \\
 \mathfrak{u}(5) \arrow[dr]& &\arrow[dl] \mathfrak{so}(6) & &
 \mathfrak{su}(3)\arrow[ddll] \\
 &  \mathfrak{so}(5)\arrow[dr]& & \phantom{\mathfrak{so}(5)} & \\
 & & \mathfrak{so}(3) \arrow[d]& & \\
 & & \mathfrak{so}(2) & & \\
\end{tikzcd}\quad\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={dash},column sep=0.2ex]
 & & A_5\arrow[lld]\arrow[rrd]\arrow[d] & & \\
 A_4 \arrow[dr]& &\arrow[dl] D_3 & &
 A_2\arrow[ddll] \\
 &  B_2\arrow[dr]& & \phantom{B_2} & \\
 & & B_2 \arrow[d]& & \\
 & & D_1 & & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 especially for using fraktur for the algebras `;-)`

Comment: @campa Thanks! I did not correct the missing `\mathfrak{u}(1)` factors, nor point out that `D_1` is, at least, "unusual".